# From single site to multi site of an existing site broke all pages images

Tags: files, multi-sites

I had a single site that is running in prod. We wanted to use the multi site feature of Drupal 7 because a few site will be using the same core code. So I moved the default/files/ to mysite.com/files like it was suggested. I created a settings.php that point to my existing DB. Everything worked fine until I reach a page that was created from the CMS and pointed to images in the default/files/ folder.

I understand that somewhere I need to change the image source paths from default/files to mysite.com/files but I can't find where. I find a lot of examples [like this one](http://snipplr.com/view/7364/mysql-find-and-replace-drupal-filepaths-in-files-table/) stating that I need to run a sql script in the files table. The thing is, there is no files table... I figure it must be for Drupal 6 or older. I am on Drupal 7 and can't find where to change the images path. I found a table called file_managed which looks like the right place but all uri are ex: public://folderUnderFiles/image.png. There must be a way to change the public:// to point to my new folder!

Comment: Have you tried setting $conf['file_public_path'] in your settings.php? E.g. $conf['file_public_path'] = 'sites/mysite.com/files'

Answer (score 0):

I reckon that the paths which are stored in the database refer to the old url. In such case, you need to run a SQL command inside MySQL that corrects the paths.

To fix entries inside **field_data_body** table, you can run this command:

```
UPDATE field_data_body SET body_value = REPLACE(body_value, 'sites/all/files', 'sites/mysite.com/files');
```

You have to do the same for the corresponding revision table.

Answer (score 0):

you can find the public folder information under mysite.com/admin/config/media/file-system

there you can change the folder contained in public, so that the token is directed to the correct folder in the database